# Regular Expression to allow an empty string or a string with specific length

Tags: regex

Hi I am having trouble trying to create a regex that will allow me to have the field empty or a string with length 9 if populated.

The current regex im using is: `^[0-9]{9}`

Which works if the field is mandatory, however we have a new requirement that this can also be empty. I've tried `^[0-9]{0|9`} but obviously that doesnt work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just make a normal string comparison to test whether the value is empty. No need for a regular expression here.

Comment: @FelixKling That requires JS, but doesn't work with [`<input pattern=`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-pattern)

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Why do you assume that the expression is used in the context of JavaScript or even HTML? There is no indication of that in the question.

Comment: Right. I was trying to say that it may be impossible to test for an empty string by other means than the RegEx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^(|[0-9]{9})$
```

Should do the trick.

**Edit:** But seriously; do what @Felix Kling suggests in a comment: test the string via a `.length` property, `.equals("")` or the like.

Comment: Great, thanks Jensgram. Not sure if it is because of the application im developing for but it doesn't allow me to use that expression. However tweeking your regex a bit it worked. Cheers! ^(|\d{9})$

Comment: @Redseven Great. Didn't realize this was related to the HTML5 `pattern` attribute.